# Can OpenVPN routes be stored in a database?

Tags: vpn, database, openvpn

I'm trying to develop a simple custom intranet web-based tool to manage OpenVPN routes so that they can be added and removed without having to edit the config file. Is there any way to make OpenVPN read these routes from a database (MySQL/PostgreSQL), or even a separate file outside the main configuration folder?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is make your web based tool generate the configuration files and deploy them over FTP or similar to the client machines or to a publicly available location. Then you can point your OpenVPN clients to read that file for configuration when an update happens.